# Project Euler #4 ArrayList doesn't add Integers

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I'm trying to solve some Project Euler Problems currently. I can't figure out why the ArrayList doesn't add the Integers.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class largestPalindromeProduct {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> largestPalindrome = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int x = 999; x >= 100; x--) {
            for (int y = 999; y >= 100; y--) {
                int result = x * y;
                if(isPalindrome(result)) {
                    largestPalindrome.add(result);
                    break;
                    // System.out.println("Added Palindrome: " +result);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Collections.max(largestPalindrome));
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int n) {
        String newN = Integer.toString(n);
        // System.out.println("newN =" +newN);
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(newN);
        // System.out.println("sBuilder reverse = " +sBuilder.reverse());
        if (newN.equals(sBuilder.reverse())) {
        return true;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

These are the Exceptions I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at java.util.Collections.max(Collections.java:669)
    at largestPalindromeProduct.main(largestPalindromeProduct.java:18)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `isPalindrome` method is returning false *all* the time because you're comparing a type `StringBuilder` and a type `String` with [`String#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) hence *nothing* will be added to the ArrayList, meaning that [`String#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) not only compares the contents of the objects being compared but also their types, this is where the problem occurs, the objects being compared could potentially have the same contents *but* due to the fact that one is a type `String` and the other is of type `StringBuilder`, the `if` condition will *always* result in false.

Solution to overcome the problem is to either use [`String#contentEquals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals(java.lang.StringBuffer)) which doesn't do type checking or convert the `StringBuilder` to a type `String` prior to comparison.

option 1 -

```
if (newN.contentEquals(sBuilder.reverse()))
```

option 2 -

```
if (newN.equals(sBuilder.reverse().toString()))
```

Actually, if you're using one of the modern IDE's, you should have a warning that you're comparing objects of inconvertible types. You should consider using an IDE such as IntelliJ IDEA to prevent errors as such in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply to my question. Solved the problem for me.
Normally I'm using Eclipse but currently, I'm trying to get familiar with Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

```
String newN = Integer.toString(n);
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder(newN);
if (newN.equals(sBuilder.reverse())) {
    return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

You are comparing a `String newN` to a `StringBuilder sBuilder`.
You have to convert the StringBuilder into a String first, or they will never be considered equal:

```
if (newN.equals(sBuilder.reverse().toString())) {
    return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If you're gonna refactor the `if else`, you may as well go as far as `return newN.equals(sBuilder.reverse().toString();`  :)